# How to improve a bad long-term forecasting of time series in common case

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, optimization, curve-fitting

I have two time series $d_t(t)$, $d_c(t)$, where I'm modelling charge as a function of time. Lengths of time series, $N$ are equal to $101$ data points. For the $d_t(t)$ (test sample, short-term) the time interval between observations is $t_1 = 0.1$ sec, and for the $d_c(t)$ (control sample, long-term) the time interval is $t_2 = 1$ sec. Thus, the right boundary of time for $d_t(t)$ is equal to $0.1\times 100 = 10$ sec, and the right boundary of time for $d_c(t)$ is equal to $1 \times 100 = 100$ sec. Both $d_t(t)$, $d_c(t)$ are correspond to the one experiment. The accuracy of measurements is $tol=0.001$.

Here's some sample data and visualization,

```
dtest <- data.frame(
   TIME = seq(0,100,by=1),
   CHARGE=c(-1.824, -1.150, -1.112, -1.097, -1.090, -1.085, -1.080, -1.075, -1.072, -1.069, 
            -1.067, -1.064, -1.061, -1.060, -1.058, -1.056, -1.055, -1.052, -1.051, -1.050, 
            -1.049, -1.048, -1.048, -1.045, -1.044, -1.043, -1.042, -1.041, -1.040, -1.039, 
            -1.038, -1.037, -1.037, -1.036, -1.036, -1.034, -1.034, -1.033, -1.032, -1.032, 
            -1.031, -1.031, -1.030, -1.030, -1.029, -1.029, -1.028, -1.027, -1.027, -1.028, 
            -1.028, -1.026, -1.025, -1.025, -1.026, -1.024, -1.025, -1.023, -1.023, -1.023, 
            -1.023, -1.023, -1.022, -1.021, -1.020, -1.020, -1.020, -1.019, -1.019, -1.018, 
            -1.018, -1.018, -1.018, -1.017, -1.016, -1.017, -1.017, -1.016, -1.015, -1.015, 
            -1.015, -1.014, -1.014, -1.013, -1.013, -1.012, -1.012, -1.011, -1.011, -1.011, 
            -1.011, -1.010, -1.011, -1.010, -1.010, -1.009, -1.008, -1.008, -1.008, -1.008, -1.008))


dcont <- data.frame(
   TIME = seq(0,100,by=1),
   CHARGE=c(-1.827, -1.071, -1.056, -1.047, -1.039, -1.034, -1.030, -1.027, -1.025, -1.020, 
            -1.017, -1.016, -1.013, -1.010, -1.009, -1.006, -1.007, -1.004, -1.004, -1.002, 
            -1.000, -0.999, -0.997, -0.997, -0.995, -0.995, -0.993, -0.991, -0.991, -0.991, 
            -0.989, -0.988, -0.988, -0.986, -0.985, -0.984, -0.984, -0.984, -0.982, -0.982, 
            -0.981, -0.981, -0.979, -0.978, -0.977, -0.976, -0.975, -0.975, -0.975, -0.974, 
            -0.973, -0.973, -0.972, -0.972, -0.971, -0.970, -0.970, -0.970, -0.969, -0.967, 
            -0.966, -0.966, -0.966, -0.966, -0.966, -0.965, -0.965, -0.964, -0.964, -0.963, 
            -0.962, -0.961, -0.962, -0.962, -0.962, -0.960, -0.960, -0.959, -0.959, -0.958, 
            -0.958, -0.958, -0.958, -0.957, -0.956, -0.956, -0.955, -0.955, -0.955, -0.955, 
            -0.955, -0.954, -0.953, -0.953, -0.954, -0.952, -0.952, -0.951, -0.952, -0.951, -0.952))
```

[image]

As we can see from figure above the data from start region is increasing exponentially $f(x)=(1+exp(-x/t))$, later they are increasing (stationary) with linear rule, like $f(x)=kx+b$.

I'd like to forecast a value of $d_t(t)$ at time point $t=100$ sec, i.e. I have 10 seconds of history and want to forecast out 90 seconds. Then verify the forecasting $d_t^p(t=100)$ with corresponding value from the $d_c(t=100)$. The forecasting is satisfactory, if $$0.95 \times d_c(t) \leq d_t^p(t)\leq 1.05 \times d_c(t).$$
On physical grounds, the experimental data can be described with an exponential function $f(x) = a \times (1+exp(-(x/\tau)))$, where $a$, $\tau$ are parameters. I have been doing curve-fitting $d(t)$ in **R** using `nlminb`. The initial values of the parameters for optimization are chosen based on the physical characteristics of the process: `parConv <- c(a=-0.762,tau=5.88)`. The result is below: $a= -1.03084$, $\tau= 0.50464$. Unfortunatly, the forecasting $f(t=100)=-1.030845$ does not satisfy to the range:

$$f(t=100) = -1.030845 \bar{\in} [0.95 \cdot (-0.952), 1.05 \cdot (-0.952)]=[-0.9044, -0.9996].$$

I have tried to split the original time series $d_t(t)$ into two parts: $d_{t_1}(t=1..10)$ and $d_{t_2}(t=11..101)$, then I have approximated the $d_{t_2}(t=11..101)$ using a linear function $f_1(x)=kx+b$ and a polynomial $f_2(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.

Result are better but not satisfy to the range:

$f_1(x)=-1.05851+x \cdot 5.61364\cdot 10^{-4}$, and $f_2(x)=-1.0718+x\cdot 0.0012+x^2 \cdot (-5.86943\cdot 10^{-6})$, `Adj. R-Square = 0,9815`. Then I have obtained the forecasts: $f_1(t=100)=-1.002374$ and $f_2(t=100)= -1.010494$.

**My question is**: How to improve a bad long-term forecasting of time series in common case?

**Another possible solutions are:**

1. Apply function `ln()` to the original data $d_t(t)$ and repeat fitting.
2. To use an exponential function and to assign greater weight to the $k$ last points (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539287/how-to-force-specific-points-in-curve-fitting)).
3. To use some alternative models, for example, [Autoregressive moving-average model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model), _https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backcasting.

Example code:

```
library(minpack.lm)
library(ggplot2)
library(optimx)

d <- data.frame(
   TIME = seq(0,100,by=1),
   CHARGE=c(-1.824, -1.150, -1.112, -1.097, -1.090, -1.085, -1.080, -1.075, -1.072, -1.069, 
            -1.067, -1.064, -1.061, -1.060, -1.058, -1.056, -1.055, -1.052, -1.051, -1.050, 
            -1.049, -1.048, -1.048, -1.045, -1.044, -1.043, -1.042, -1.041, -1.040, -1.039, 
            -1.038, -1.037, -1.037, -1.036, -1.036, -1.034, -1.034, -1.033, -1.032, -1.032, 
            -1.031, -1.031, -1.030, -1.030, -1.029, -1.029, -1.028, -1.027, -1.027, -1.028, 
            -1.028, -1.026, -1.025, -1.025, -1.026, -1.024, -1.025, -1.023, -1.023, -1.023, 
            -1.023, -1.023, -1.022, -1.021, -1.020, -1.020, -1.020, -1.019, -1.019, -1.018, 
            -1.018, -1.018, -1.018, -1.017, -1.016, -1.017, -1.017, -1.016, -1.015, -1.015, 
            -1.015, -1.014, -1.014, -1.013, -1.013, -1.012, -1.012, -1.011, -1.011, -1.011, 
            -1.011, -1.010, -1.011, -1.010, -1.010, -1.009, -1.008, -1.008, -1.008, -1.008, -1.008))


d1 <- data.frame(
   TIME = seq(0,100,by=1),
   CHARGE=c(-1.827, -1.071, -1.056, -1.047, -1.039, -1.034, -1.030, -1.027, -1.025, -1.020, 
            -1.017, -1.016, -1.013, -1.010, -1.009, -1.006, -1.007, -1.004, -1.004, -1.002, 
            -1.000, -0.999, -0.997, -0.997, -0.995, -0.995, -0.993, -0.991, -0.991, -0.991, 
            -0.989, -0.988, -0.988, -0.986, -0.985, -0.984, -0.984, -0.984, -0.982, -0.982, 
            -0.981, -0.981, -0.979, -0.978, -0.977, -0.976, -0.975, -0.975, -0.975, -0.974, 
            -0.973, -0.973, -0.972, -0.972, -0.971, -0.970, -0.970, -0.970, -0.969, -0.967, 
            -0.966, -0.966, -0.966, -0.966, -0.966, -0.965, -0.965, -0.964, -0.964, -0.963, 
            -0.962, -0.961, -0.962, -0.962, -0.962, -0.960, -0.960, -0.959, -0.959, -0.958, 
            -0.958, -0.958, -0.958, -0.957, -0.956, -0.956, -0.955, -0.955, -0.955, -0.955, 
            -0.955, -0.954, -0.953, -0.953, -0.954, -0.952, -0.952, -0.951, -0.952, -0.951, -0.952))


(g1 <- ggplot(d,aes(TIME,CHARGE))+geom_point())
g1+geom_smooth()  ## with loess fit

# Parameter choices:
parConv <- c(a=-0.762,tau=5.88) #

#Perturbed parameters:
parStart      <- parConv
parStart["a"] <- parStart["a"]+3e-4

Ebos <- -1.161 # start value at x=0

#The formulae:
RCCircuits<-function(parS,x)
    with(as.list(parS), 
                       ifelse(x==0, Ebos, a*(1+exp(-(x/tau))) ) 
         )

# A sum-of-squares function
ssqfun <- function(parS, Observed, x) {
   sum(ResidFun(parS, Observed, x)^2)
}

# Local minimizer for smooth nonlinear functions subject to bound-constrained parameters
opt1 <- nlminb(start=parStart, objective = ssqfun,
    Observed = d$CHARGE, x = d$TIME,
    control= list(eval.max=5000,iter.max=5000))

parNLM <- opt1$par

#SSE Review:
sapply(list(parConv,parNLM),
  ssqfun,Observed=d$CHARGE,x=d$TIME)  

pred0 <- RCCircuits(as.list(parConv), d$TIME)
pred1 <- RCCircuits(as.list(parNLM),  d$TIME)

# forecasting at t=100 sec
pred100 <- RCCircuits(as.list(parNLM), 1000)
```

Comment: Great write up. Is the problem because your forecasts sit outside the range of because they are not accurate enough when back-casting? In terms of which approach would be best, sometimes the only way to test that is to give em a try and compare against a test set

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have 10 seconds worth of history and want to forecast out 90 seconds, i.e., nine times as far as your history is long. In such a situation, I would not expect very high accuracy.

Comment: @EvanMiller, thanks you for point of view. Back-casting approuch is new for me.

Comment: When I think about it @Nick, backcasting might not be the greatest idea in this situation - but you might want to try fitting a more general model. You can do this either by using a training/test split and Cross Validation in building the model or to ensemble a couple of the models you've talked about. But in the end of it as previously noted, you still might not get the greatest forecast.